# Como checar uma ImagePattern de um Rectangle no JavaFX?

Tags: css, javafx, imageview, booleano

Estou tentando checar neste método se meu Square, o qual herda de Rectangle, foi preenchido com uma ImagePattern por meio da função getFill():

```
 public boolean HouseIsValid(House Square) {

    return (Square.getFill().equals(green) || Square.getFill().equals(lightgreen));
}
```

Sendo green e lightgreen duas ImagePatterns as quais são declaradas neste método em meu construtor:

```
 public void setImagePatterns() {

    ImageView image = new ImageView("/Images/greenhouse.jpg");
    green = new ImagePattern(image.getImage());

    image = new ImageView("/Images/lightgreenhouse.jpg");
    lightgreen = new ImagePattern(image.getImage());
}
```

Existe na classe de meu Square um método para determinar a ImagePattern dele, eis que num dado momento do meu código principal, eu mudo a ImagePattern para aquelas acima:

```
public void setFill(String url) {

    ImageView image = new ImageView(url);
    setBackground(new ImagePattern(image.getImage()));

    setFill(background);
}
```

Porém, ele retorna falso, quando deveria retornar verdadeiro. Eu gostaria de saber o que está errado na validação do primeiro método. Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O método está retornando `false` porque os objetos comparados são diferentes.
Em java, quando você cria uma classe, ela herda da classe `Object`. Um dos métodos de `Object` é o `equals`. O método `equals` de `Object` retorna `true` se as duas instâncias comparadas forem as mesmas.

No seu caso, você cria uma instância nesse ponto:

```
green = new ImagePattern(image.getImage());
```

Porém nesse outro ponto, você cria outra instância:

```
setBackground(new ImagePattern(image.getImage()));
```

Então, quando você compara os `ImagePattern`, você está comparando objetos diferentes.

Para que o método `equals` funcione de maneira diferente, por exemplo, retornar `true` se os paths forem iguais, é necessário sobrescrevê-lo. No seu caso, a validação não pode ser feita utilizando o `equals`. Infelizmente as classes `ImagePattern` e `Paint` não fornecem nenhum método que dê para realizar esse teste. Você poderia guardar o path das imagens e fazer a validação através do path.